# Database app, accessible from Mac, iPad and Web

Tags: database, macos, ipad

I feel very out of my depth with this query, but not being able to do it isn't really an option so I am going to have to learn how one way or another.

I have been tasked with building an application / database for a Chauffeur company. I have done similar things before in Microsoft Access for other customers, hence getting this request, but this customer wants to be able to run the app on their Mac, and not install Windows. My only real experience of coding is HTML/CSS and some VBA when using Microsoft Access. For these Access DBs I have created separate front and back end files to allow multi user access and also remote access (the back end file being kept on the company server).

So onto my query (apologies for dragging it out)...

I need to be able to build something that the single user can open and run on his Mac, so he can view, add, change jobs and their details. He also needs to have the same access on his iPad, although purely viewing would suffice.

As regards the web access, basically he wants to be able to go onto his "Booking System" application, go to "New Job" and send a link to his client, where they would click the link in a browser, fill in the details (Name, Contact Number, collection and drop off addresses, collection date and time etc...) and when they submit this form the details be updated on his booking system.

My issue is I do not really know where to start. I just need some pointers as to where to get started. Is it an issue of building a MySQL database back end and then hosting this somewhere and linking different front ends to it etc...

Comment: While I haven't really dealt too much situations like this, it sounds like something that could be solved by hosting a web service to act as a layer between the various users' apps and the database. That prevents the applications from needing to connect directly to the database, allowing you to use whatever you want to server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with multiple clients, the web is your best answer.  For the cheapest hosting route, you can find good, inexpensive PHP and MySQL hosting that will provide what you need.  You can design the front end with HTML/CSS, use PHP to develop the logic and data access, and use MySQL to host the data.

The Mac and iPad can access the application via the web URL--you will not be building an iOS app, rather the user will access the web site through a web browser.  You can use some pretty neat tools like jQuery UI Mobile to create an app-like experience, but if you need to support multiple clients on a small budget, an iOS app and separate web site is not the way to go.

Make sure you have some PHP expertise available or figure this part out.  There are tons of great resources on the web to get started.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply John.
There will only be one user of the "booking system", he just wants to be able to access the details on the road on his ipad.

The only other "users" will be the clients, as he wants to be able to send them effectively a blank booking sheet, with just say a unique ID such as job number, and they fill it out submit it and the details appear on his system. Would I be able to achieve all this using the method you outlined?

Comment: Yes, this method is the most flexible, and will allow what you are describing.  You can at some point later create an iPad if you want and have the budget for it.  If you foresee this kind of enhancement, you might want to think about creating services so that all access to your database goes through the same centralized code.  But assuming the web route is good enough, you may not need to bite off this kind of complexity.

Comment: Thanks for the advice John. Just have to polish up my HTML and CSS now, and get learning PHP and MySQL.